Jenkins JDK tool configuration doesn't list JDK 21 (Adoptium)
We encountered an issue in Jenkins today with jobs that use the JDK tool configured to use Adoptium's JDK version 21. The problem is that JDK 21 doesn't appear in the dropdown list of available versions when configuring the JDK tool.
Steps:

Configured the JDK tool in Jenkins to use Adoptium.
Verified that earlier versions (e.g., JDK 17, JDK 11) are * listed and work as expected.
Confirmed that JDK 21 is available at adoptium

Observations:

The JDK 21 option is missing entirely from the dropdown list in the tool configuration.
Jobs using tool jdk21 fail because Jenkins cannot resolve the JDK version.

Environment details:

Jenkins version: 2.479
JDK versions configured: [jdk8, JDK 11, JDK 17, JDK 21]

Which is te error?. Last friday the plugin loads jdk21 versions correctly.
There is some workaround?

Finally restarting jenkins the plugin has been able to list versions > jdk21

Currently experiencing identical issue.
No JDK21 in dropdown (noticed after failed builds).
Was working as expected Friday.
Direct download of tar.gz workaround succeeds.
Jenkins 2.485
Eclipse Temurin Installer Plugin 1.5

Ticket opened:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-74919

Resolved with refresh of update center.  Details in ticket.
